# How to calculate aspect ratio of car in matlab?

Tags: matlab, object-detection

I am trying to detect a car in a video. After the background subtraction we get the following image:

Now I surround the car with a bounding box.

```
blobAnalysis = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
'AreaOutputPort', false, 'CentroidOutputPort', false, ...
'MinimumBlobArea', 150);
bbox = step(blobAnalysis, filteredForeground);
result = insertShape(frame, 'Rectangle', bbox, 'Color', 'green');
```

The next step is to calculate the aspect ratio of the bounding box. How do I do that ?

The link to the matlab website hosting the code is :
https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detecting-cars-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html?prodcode=VP&language=en

Comment: The width divided by the height................

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bounding box (bbox) to be 1 x 4 matrix in MATLAB, which specifies x, y, width and height respectively. Then, your aspect ratio would simply be ratio of width to the height of bbox.

```
aspect_ratio = bbox(1, 3) / bbox(1, 4);
```